# Locking pairs of mutually referencing resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

Consider the following:

```
// There are guys:
class Guy {
    // Each guy can have a buddy:
    Guy* buddy; // When a guy has a buddy, he is his buddy's buddy, i.e:
                // assert(!buddy || buddy->buddy == this);

public:
    // When guys are birthed into the world they have no buddy:
    Guy()
        : buddy{}
    {}

    // But guys can befriend each other:
    friend void befriend(Guy& a, Guy& b) {
        // Except themselves:
        assert(&a != &b);

        // Their old buddies (if any), lose their buddies:
        if (a.buddy) { a.buddy->buddy = {}; }
        if (b.buddy) { b.buddy->buddy = {}; }

        a.buddy = &b;
        b.buddy = &a;
    }

    // When a guy moves around, he keeps track of his buddy
    // and lets his buddy keep track of him:
    friend void swap(Guy& a, Guy& b) {
        std::swap(a.buddy, b.buddy);
        if (a.buddy) { a.buddy->buddy = &a; }
        if (b.buddy) { b.buddy->buddy = &b; }
    }
    Guy(Guy&& guy)
        : Guy()
    {
        swap(*this, guy);
    }
    Guy& operator=(Guy guy) {
        swap(*this, guy);
        return *this;
    }

    // When a Guy dies, his buddy loses his buddy.
    ~Guy() {
        if (buddy) { buddy->buddy = {}; }
    }
};
```

All is well so far, but now I want this to work when buddies are used in different threads. No problem, let's just stick `std::mutex` in `Guy`:

```
class Guy {
    std::mutex mutex;

    // same as above...
};
```

Now I just have to lock mutexes of both guys before linking or unlinking the pair of them.

This is where I am stumped. Here are failed attempts (using the destructor as an example):

1. Deadlock:

   ```
   ~Guy() {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
       if (buddy) {
           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> buddyLock{buddy->mutex};
           buddy->buddy = {};
       }
   }
   ```

   When two buddies are destroyed at around the same time, it is possible that each of them locks their own mutex, before trying to lock their buddies' mutexes, thus resulting in a deadlock.
2. Race condition:

   Okay so we just have to lock mutexes in consistent order, either manually or with `std::lock`:

   ```
   ~Guy() {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex, std::defer_lock};
       if (buddy) {
           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> buddyLock{buddy->mutex, std::defer_lock};
           std::lock(lock, buddyLock);
           buddy->buddy = {};
       }
   }
   ```

   Unfortunately, to get to buddy's mutex we have to access `buddy` which at this point is not protected by any lock and may be in the process of being modified from another thread, which is a race condition.
3. Not scalable:

   Correctness *can* be attained with a global mutex:

   ```
   static std::mutex mutex;
   ~Guy() {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
       if (buddy) { buddy->buddy = {}; }
   }
   ```

   But this is undesirable for performance and scalability reasons.

So is this possible to do without global lock? How?

Comment: I think you need to separate the concerns of "buddyness" and "guyness". i.e. a new class called "Guys" which contains references to zero, one or two guys.

Comment: @RichardHodges how would that help? Same issue would exist between `Guys` and each `Guy`.

Comment: I sort of agree with @RichardHodges. Conceptually, it seems like what needs to be synchronized is the relationship between the `Guy`s, not the `Guy`s themselves. This might be done with a mutex shared between the `Guy`s, which is locked whenever the buddy-relationship is severed (either when a new `Guy` is befriended or one is destroyed).

Comment: I really like this challenge. I'm a critical of 'dining philosophers' problem because while it showcases deadlocking it isn't a very realistic model of a typical system because the number of locks is the same as the number of threads and that's an atypical problem. I was wondering what the application might be. All I can think of is a collection of workers - midwives who birth Guys, matchmakers who befriend and unfriend them and reapers who randomly kill them.

Comment: @Persixty, the actual application is a future/promise-like pair of objects that unlike their `std` counterparts do not do dynamic memory allocation and so can't be implemented via shared state. `befriend` is a `pipe`-like operation that turns two pairs `promiseA->futureA` and `promiseB->futureB` into one `promiseA->futureB`.

Comment: @yurikilochek Your `Guy` model is symmetric which is what makes it a challenge. If it's `promiseX->futureY` you should probably use a lock hierarchy model where you always lock the promises first. You probably don't need the unlock-relock-and-check step below. If contention is low use `std::lock(..promises...)` and then `std::lock(...futures...)` no deadlock risk if consistently done in that order.

Comment: @Persixty symmetry is irrelevant, you can impose arbitrary order on guys (e.g. by their address) to make the problem asymmetric. What you can't do, is always lock the promises first, because when a future needs to get to a promise it is necessarily locked first to protect the promise pointer. Likewise in the other direction.

Comment: @yurikilochek That depends on what your algorithm is that you haven't specified in any detail. It may be that promises have futures have other promises and so on but it there may still be no deadlock risk if the objects are strictly generational. I have a massive tree structure of `Node-Node` but it is strictly tiered and locks are only acquired singly and in that order so no deadlock. If futures can loop back and lock promises 'behind' them then yes you need to do something like unlock-relock-check.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) isn't a race condition (per se) nor does it risk deadlock.

`std::lock` will use a deadlock-free algorithm to obtain the two locks. They will be some kind of (unspecified) try-and-retreat method.

An alternative is to determine an arbitrary lock order for example using the physical address of the objects.

You've correctly excluded the possibility that an objects buddy is itself so there's no risk of trying to `lock()` the same `mutex` twice.

I say isn't a race condition per se because what that code will do is ensure integrity that if a has buddy b then b has buddy a for all a and b.

The fact that one moment after befriending two objects they might be unfriended by another thread is presumably what you intend or addressed by other synchronization.

Note also that when you're befriending and may unfriend the friends of the new friends you need to lock ALL the objects at once.
That is the two 'to be' friends and their current friends (if any).
Consequently you need to lock 2,3 or 4 mutexes.

`std::lock` unfortunately doesn't take an array but there is a version that does that in boost or you need to address it by hand.

To clarify, I'm reading the examples of possible destructors as models. Synchronization on the same locks would be required in all the relevant members (e.g. `befriend()`, `swap()` and `unfriend()` if that is required). Indeed the issue of locking 2,3 or 4  applies to the `befriend()` member.

Furthermore the destructor is probably the worst example because as mentioned in a comment it's illogical that an object is destructible but may be in lock contention with another thread. Some synchronization surely needs to exist in the wider program to make that impossible at which point the lock in the destructor is redundant.

Indeed a design which ensures `Guy` objects have no buddy *before* destruction would seem like a good idea and a debug pre-condition that checks `assert(buddy==nullptr)` in the destructor. Sadly that can't be left as a run-time exception because throwing exceptions in destructors can cause program termination (`std::terminate()`).

In fact the real challenge (which may depend on the surrounding program) is how to unfriend when befriending. That would appear to require a try-retreat loop:

1. Lock a and b.
2. Find out if they have buddies.
3. If they're already buddies - you're done.
4. If they have other buddies, unlock a & b, and lock a and b and their buddies (if any).
5. Check that the buddies haven't changed, if they have go again.
6. Adjust the relevant members.

It's a question for the surrounding program whether that risks live-lock but any try-retreat method suffers the same risk.

What won't work is `std::lock()` a & b then `std::lock()` the buddies because that does risk deadlock.

So to answer the question - yes, it is possible without a global lock but that depends on the surrounding program. It may be in a population of many `Guy` objects contention is rare and liveness is high.
But it may be that there are a small number of objects that are hotly contended (possibly in a large population) that results in a problem. That can't be assessed without understanding the wider application.

One way to resolve that would be lock escalation which in effect piecemeal falls back to a global lock. In essence that would mean if there were too many trips round the re-try loop a global semaphore would be set ordering all threads to go into global lock mode for a while. A while might be a number of actions or a period of time or until contention on the global lock subsides!

So the final answer is "yes it's absolutely possible unless it doesn't work in which case 'no'".

Comment: Read #2 carefully again. The problem is that I can't get to second mutex safely without locking the first one. Locking the first mutex results in a deadlock as per #1 and not locking it - in a race condition as `buddy` pointer remains unprotected.

Comment: @yurikilochek Only if `std::lock` is broken! `std::lock` uses a deadlock avoidance algorithm. That's it's purpose. Make sure you lock everything you need in one go! NB: Your destructor is a worry though. If you've triggered the destructor I'd think you had (by other synchronization means) ensured no other thread could be accessing the object in destruction. But that doesn't (necessarily) apply to its `buddy`.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock

Comment: at step #4 of your algorithm there is a race condition: once a&b are unlocked after getting pointers to their buddies, the buddies can be destroyed, so it would try to lock non-existing mutexes.

Comment: @yurikilochek As I mentioned in the text the problem is with the lifecycle. You need to deal with lifecycle separately. If two threads are in contention for an object and one destroys it the other thread will fail.
The idea that a mutex in the destructor makes it thread safe is fundamentally flawed. You need to make sure when an object is destructed only one thread has a reference to it.
That's not a problem with that step it's a problem with the overall design you need to address. But without know what your application does I can't suggest an answer...

Comment: @yurikilochek I've now read your other note. If the objects aren't dynamic and on the stack you need to make sure the threads have no reference to them or themselves stopped (use `join()`) before reaching the `Guy` destructors at the end of the scope. If you destroy a mutex while another thread is waiting on it the program fails. You've can't protect a destructor with a mutex in the object.

Comment: Sure you can protect the destructor, just don't let the object die by not leaving the destructor until the lock is acquired and the pair is disconnected.

Comment: @yurikilochek You can't protect the destructor with a lock that is logically destroyed in the destructor. If another thread is waiting on that lock because it's in the destructor it will acquire a lock that is about to be, is being or has been destroyed. That is a race condition. A global lock could work but as you point out scales poorly.

Comment: As a member object, the mutex is destroyed after the destructor, not inside it. Therefore not leaving the destructor ensures the mutex stays alive as long as needed.

Comment: @yurikilochek Correct but the other thread *just* acquired it as you leave your destructor code remember! So the other thread is doing something holding the mutex *while* it's destroyed. That is definitely a race condition.

Comment: That is not possible because once your release the `buddy->mutex`, `buddy->buddy` will be reset to null, thus once the other thread poking buddy successfully​ locks its mutex, it will already see it detached and won't reach the mutex that is about to be destroyed.

Comment: @yurikilochek Look at the lock in the destructor. If that acquisition could ever be in contention there's a problem. Imagine that just after it is acquired in the destructor a thread is already waiting on it. If that can't happen you don't need it for exclusion if you do need it then it won't work because it will be destroyed in an unhandled race between the built-in destructor code and the thread that immediately acquired it! I see what you're trying to do to make sure buddy is nulled but another thread accessing that object is what's in trouble.

Comment: @yurikilochek It's asking us to move to chat. Are you finding this conversation productive enough to do that?